# Jquery toggle() makes my navbar flicker

Tags: jquery, banner

I have a banner over my fixed navbar. When I scroll through it and my navbar gets to the top of the browser, it starts flickering non-stop in that position.

I think it's related to the jquery `toggleClass()`, but I have no idea how to fix it.

When I inspect the navbar in that position, it just keeps adding and removing the `has-monster-banner` class, causing it to flicker.

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {

    if (event.slot.getAdUnitPath() === '/1025113/1220x200' && !event.isEmpty) {
        jQuery('body').addClass('has-monster-banner');
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            jQuery('body').toggleClass('has-monster-banner', jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 220);
        });
    }
}
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you get flickering elements while using jquery think of what causes it. Apperantly your toggle function is called forever. I think it might be related to scrollTop.

What you should do is that decide when it should stop calling that function. then by using a flag variable do as follows

```
var flag = false;
if(mycondition && !flag){
    Do whatever you want...
    flag = true;
}
if(restart condition){
    flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Im not really sure how i can use .stop() for a specific part like <=221